# Creating my own CMD in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, shell, cmd

I'm in need of help with this program which I'm trying to create.
I'm pretty new to programming in general, so please bear with me.

So what I'm trying to create right now, is my own command prompt, and with that said, let me tell you what I want in the command prompt.

As we know from the normal CMD on windows OS systems, we have our input box(or whatever) which we can use to type commands, such as "start google.com", or "ipconfig" etc...
and we have our output, which tells us the results from the commands we typed.

And I wanna create the exact same thing, just with my own UI and some extras which I'm gonna add later.

Here is my issue tho, whenever I type the shell command in my textbox and execute it, it prints out the exception message, so basically it doesn't run the command.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As Object, e As KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
    Dim tmp As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs = e
    If tmp.KeyChar = ChrW(Keys.Enter) Then
        Try
            Shell(TextBox1.Text)
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Green
            RichTextBox1.SelectedText = TextBox1.Text
        Catch ex As Exception
            RichTextBox1.Clear()
            RichTextBox1.SelectionColor = Color.Red
            RichTextBox1.SelectedText = ex.Message
        End Try
        TextBox1.Text = ""
    Else

    End If
End Sub
```

I'd really like some examples if possible, since I'm new and I probably wouldn't understand much without examples.

Comment: You should use [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53ezey2s.aspx) instead of `Shell()`.

Comment: Yes, but what if I wanna use the command "ipconfig". Would that still be optionable with process.start?

Comment: If you want to use any command that requires command line parameters you can only use Process.Start because Shell() doesn't allow parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Using a process object instead of a shell is a lot better of an option for having a conversation with cmd. Here's an example of a simple function that you can pass commands to that will return the command's response. This example just does one command/response, but you can use the same process shown below to enter into a dialog with cmd.exe:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MsgBox(ExecuteCommand("ipconfig /all"))
End Sub

Private Function ExecuteCommand(ByVal command As String) As String
    Dim response As String = Nothing
    Dim p As New System.Diagnostics.Process
    Dim psi As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd.exe")
    With psi
        .UseShellExecute = False
        .RedirectStandardInput = True
        .RedirectStandardOutput = True
        .RedirectStandardError = True
        .CreateNoWindow = True
    End With
    p = Process.Start(psi)
    With p
        .StandardInput.WriteLine(command)
        .StandardInput.Close()
        If .StandardError.Peek > 0 Then
            response = .StandardError.ReadToEnd
            .StandardError.Close()
        Else
            response = .StandardOutput.ReadToEnd
            .StandardOutput.Close()
        End If
        .Close()
    End With
    Return response
End Function
```

And as you'll see if you run the code above, you can certainly use commands like ipconfig

Comment: Thanks man, this helped with the issue I had :) I appreciate it.

Comment: Hey man, I'm having another issue, now whenever I make a false command or a command that doesn't exist, it outputs it in a msgbox, could I do so it outputs the exception in my richtextbox1.text? And if I make calls like "iowgoier" or "lmao" or something without a "start" infront of the call/command, it doesn't recognize the problem and just prints out the exact same thing that I typed in.

Comment: No problem, just need to add some handling for the process' standarderror...See edits to the executecommand function above

Comment: @GuestAnon, you can accept the answer , if it meets the requirement.

Comment: Accept what answer? :D

Comment: From SO Help Documentation: [What should I do when someone answers my question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)